# change text of placeholder when clicking on arabic

Tags: jquery, html

I have an input with placeholder "explore places"

```
  <form id='search'>
    <input type='text' id='geolocate' placeholder='Explore Places'/>
  </form>
```

how can change the text inside jquery when clicking on a div lets say here is my html

```
<div id='language-select'>
    <ul class='language'> 
        <li><a class='first active' id='english' class='satellite_terrain'>English</a></li>
        <li><a class='second' id='arabic' class='satellite_terrain'>عربي</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

when clicking on english placeholder should be 'Explore Places' when arabic should be 'Explore Places ar'

Comment: You have not posted your JS code.

Comment: normally change the value of the attribute `placeholder`

Comment: @Satpal i dont have the jquery code

Answer (score 0):

just use [$.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to change, like:

```
$("#arabic").click(function() {
    $("#geolocate").attr("placeholder", "Explore Places ar");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**,

```
$('#arabic').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#geolocate').attr('placeholder','Explore Places ar');
})
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/dabugihe/1/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

Use **.attr()** :-

```
$('#arabic').click(function(){
  $('#geolocate').attr('placeholder','Explore Places ar');
})
```

Do same for English so that you can easily switch between two.

```
$('#english').click(function(){
  $('#geolocate').attr('placeholder','Explore Places');
})
```